# Saving multiple text box Data in UWP App to an external file that can be named everytime the file is saved (eg txt file) and retrieving them

Tags: uwp

I would like to save multiple text box Data in UWP App to an external file that can be named every time the file is saved (eg txt file)  and retrieve them amongst many.

I have done this in dot net apps using C# but this seems to be hard in UWP apps. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Win32 applications, UWP applications may be different in the way of saving files.

> I would like to save multiple text box Data in UWP App

I don't know how you plan to organize the contents of these `TextBox`s, but it's not difficult. You can use the `TextBox.Text` to get the contents of the text box and combine them the way you want.

> to an external file that can be named every time the file is saved (eg txt file)

I assume that you have organized the text and need to save the text to a local file.

Please note that in UWP apps, you cannot write files directly through the path. You have two ways to get the file:

1. Save the file in `LocalFolder`

```cs
public async static Task WriteHistory(string content, string fileName)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, content);
}
```

2. Open the file you want to save content with `FileOpenPicker`

```cs
public async static Task<StorageFile> OpenLocalFile(params string[] types)
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    Regex typeReg = new Regex(@"^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (type == "*" || typeReg.IsMatch(type))
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(type);
        else
            throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid file type");
    }
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    return file;
}
```

After that, you can use `await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, content);` to write the text to the selected file.

Best regards.